# removing a char from string in Unity3D

Tags: string, unity-game-engine

I am making a word game in unity3D game engine, I make a word if word spelling is wrong I want to remove a certain character from that word for making a correct spelling and then other character shift back...  in my code I have an string and want to remove a char from string.... so that when the char is removed from the center of the string other char shift back.

```
static var nextPos = 200;
static var word: String;
var sel: String;
var isClicked : boolean=false;
var xpos: float = 200;
static var i:int=0;
function start()
{
 word="";
}
function OnMouseDown()
{
    if (!isClicked) {
       isClicked = true;
       xpos = nextPos;
       sel=OnGUI();
       word=word+sel;
       nextPos += 8;
       i++;

      }
else if(isClicked)
  {
  isClicked = false;
  xpos = nextPos;
  nextPos -= 8;

}
}
function OnGUI()
{  

   if (gameObject.name == "Sphere(Clone)" && isClicked )
   {
          GUI.Label(new Rect(xpos,260,400,100), "A");
          return "A";


   }

   else if (gameObject.name == "Sphere 1(Clone)" && isClicked )
   {
          GUI.Label(new Rect(xpos,260,400,100), "B");
          return "B";

   }  

   else if (gameObject.name == "Sphere 2(Clone)" && isClicked )
   {
          GUI.Label(new Rect(xpos,260,400,100), "C");
          return "C";

   }

  GUI.Label(new Rect(xpos,280,400,100), "Value" + i);
  GUI.Label(new Rect(xpos,300,400,100), word);                      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
string value = "abcde";
string temp="";
temp = value.Substring(0, position - 1);
value = temp + value.Substring(position, value.Length);
```

Comment: What is your problem? What do you return this code to indicate position 3?

Answer (score 0):

you can check which key is pressed once your text is being displayed

this should work . you need just call it in your update function or OnGUI function

set "word" as a global variable if you use it in an Update function

I wrote this out of my head , It should work , sorry it it has any glitches.

```
               if(Input.anyKey)
    {
            string letter = Input.inputString;
            if (word.Contains(letter))
{

word.Replace(letter,"");

}

    }
```